# Compare two files in unix and add the delta to one file

Tags: linux, shell

Both files has lines of string and numeric data minimum of 2000 lines.
How to add non duplicate data from `file2.txt` to `file1.txt`.
Basically file2 has the new data lines but we also want to ensure we are not adding duplicate lines to file1.txt.

- `File1.txt` > this is the main data file
- `File2.txt` > this file has the new data we want to add to file1

thanks,

Comment: Is the order of the lines significant? Are they sorted?

Comment: The order is not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the two files together with the `-u` option to remove duplicates.

```
sort -u File1.txt File2.txt > NewFile.txt && mv NewFile.txt File1.txt
```

Comment: tried this on a 50,000 line data file and in terms of memory usage seems pretty efficient. I got the output file pretty quick. I think this is the solution for my case here.

Comment: @Barmer what does sort -u actually sort the records based on? pls note most the columns are look alike but some are different. Also does having different spacing between words makes the line to be consider as unique?

Comment: It sorts the records on the sort key. By default it's the whole line, and spaces are significant. There are options to change the key to specific fields, and ignore spacing and/or case. Read the man page.

Answer (score 2):

Another option *if* the file is sorted, just to have some choice (and I like `comm` :) )

```
comm --check-order --output-delimiter=''  -13 File1.txt File2.txt >> File1.txt
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: true, this assumes sorted indeed.

Comment: *nod*. Definitely the most efficient approach if your files are all pre-sorted. (Well -- one could also use Barmar's approach with the GNU merge-sort flag, I suppose, but I'd expect the two to be about equivalent in performance in that case).

Comment: @Wrikken the file in this case is not sorted. wondering what is "-13 " in your script?

Comment: @Vcode: `-1` = surpress lines unique to file1, `-2` = surpress lines unique to file2, `-3` = surpress lines present in both file1 and file2. Hence, `-13` means 'show only the unique lines of file2'. Both if not sorted, it doesn't do you much good. You can pre-sort hem of course, but in that case you might as well go with Barmar's answer to do it in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`, like this:

```
# grep those lines from file2 which are not in file1
grep -vFf file1 file2 > new_file2
# append the results to file1
cat new_file2 >> file1
```

Comment: Hmm. From a memory usage perspective, this smells potentially expensive. (`sort` can break its work up to keep pieces on-disk if it would need more memory than is available, but I'm not sure how `grep` is going to behave if it's trying to keep a pattern list or construct a regex from a list of sources that's exceptionally large).

Comment: On the other hand this preserves the existing order of lines and does not spend time on sorting. Depending on the use case this might be the best solution, or the only correct one, out of this three answers.

Comment: A fair argument. If I were the OP, and this method were the only way my file were going to be modified over time, I'd probably eat the expense of sorting the file *once*, and then use the `comm` approach from then on out... but you're right, there's a use case for everything here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Just did a few tests. Without `-F`, `grep` will exponentially allocate memory and get killed in a few secs by the kernel's oom killer. I've tested with a 500.000 line file of patterns and a 500.000 line text file. With `-F` (which looks like even making more sense in this question), `grep` is so damn fast, your eyes can't even blink. But of course that doesn't endlessly scale. Probably something like Hadoop would be more appropriate anyway when the files are *really* large...

Comment: @hek2mgl the file size I'm working on is 2-4Mb the first time I tried it took a considerable amount of time more than a min so I stopped the command, I tired it again and it worked instantly, so I deleted my comment. not sure what may have cause it thou!

Comment: Interesting. Is it sensitive data? Otherwise you may share it with us..

Answer (score 1):

use awk:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' File1.txt File2.txt
```

Comment: What advantage does this have over the approaches already present? It's memory-inefficient -- even moreso than the `grep -vf` approach, since this one stores even lines only found in the second file in memory, whereas that can store only lines from the preexisting file -- and I'm not sure what benefits it adds.